# How to fit using float64?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I've set all the layers in my model to use float64, yet when fitting the loss appears to still be coming out as float32 (based on the rounding I see).  I'd like to ensure that all processing under the hood is in double.  How can I guarantee that?

Comment: Please provide some reproducible code. Have you tried `tf.keras.backend.set_floatx('float64')` after importing tf?

Comment: anecdotally, you may find the performance is actually worse with so many more bits when compared to doing more prolonged processing! for example, Google Brain actually created a custom [bfloat16 type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bfloat16_floating-point_format) ([more](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/ai-machine-learning/bfloat16-the-secret-to-high-performance-on-cloud-tpus)) (which is essentially a truncated float32 so they can be converted with minimal processing) to improve the efficiency of operations in Tensorflow and related platforms

Comment: You shouldn't base this "on the rounding you see", but actually check the dtype of the tensors... You might simply be making a wrong guess.

Comment: Which tensors would I check?  I know if I manually run the outputs through my loss function it might say, e.g., 7878974328947.15673, but during training it says 7878974328947.000.  Also, setting K.set_floatx('float64') prior to other ops does expand the apparent precision.

Answer (score 1):

instead of manually setting the dtype for each layer, you can define a global policy with:

```
policy = tf.keras.mixed_precision.Policy("float64")
tf.keras.mixed_precision.set_global_policy(policy)
```

or alternativly set the backend default float:

```
tf.keras.backend.set_floatx(policyConfig)
```

In that way all layers automatically use float64.

For your loss calculation: if intitialize values you should initialize them using `tf.constant(0.0, dtype=tf.float64)` instead of only initializing with 0.0 to ensure float64.